# Hiding Google Chrome inspect elements page?

Tags: google-chrome

I can't find the escape button on the 'inspect elements' window.turn it off. There is no "x" at the top right of the screen and I'd really like to turn it off. Help!

Comment: What button? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I take it that you have the devtools un-docked correct? Click the half-shaded rectangle button at the bottom-right to dock it and you will have your x-in-a-circle back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows (or Linux), the F12 key is used for opening the inspect elements page. Try pressing F12 to close the menu.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. There should be an x button in the upper ***left*** corner of the
   popover. The reason why it's hiding there evades me. Clicking it should hide the inspect element window.
2. If using OS X, `⌥+⌘+I` will display/hide the inspect element
   window.